# How can I combine multiple objects based on the same value they have in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Item{
   var name;
   var productId;
   Item(this.name,this.productId);
}
class Price{
   List<String> listOfProductIds = [];
   double amount;
}
```

Lets say I have list of prices:

```
[["productid1","productid3"], 199.00], ["productid2","productid4"],299.00],...);
```

I have TWO different lists.

This one:

```
 [["myName","productid1"],["myNamee","productid2"]]
```

And, this one:

```
[["myName","productid3"],["myNamee","productid4"]]
```

for example, I want to retrieve items for a price of 199.00. basically I want to show `["myName","productid1"]` and `["myName","productid3"]` How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of having a `Price` class, why don't you use a `Map<double, List<String>>`, and then you could easily look up productIDs by price. (Also, I would not use `double` for prices and instead would use an `int` and store prices as cents.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is a custom use case and this cannot be done with a single statement in Dart. However, this result can be achieved with the help of the `forEach` loop in Dart.

Here is a minimal example reproducing your above problem -

```
class Prices {
  List<String> products;
  double price;

  Prices(this.products, this.price);
}

void main() {

  List<Prices> priceList = [Prices(["productid1","productid3"], 199.00), Prices(["productid2","productid4"],299.00)];

  List<List<String>> productList1 = [["myName","productid1"],["myNamee","productid2"]];

  List<List<String>> productList2 = [["myName","productid3"],["myNamee","productid4"]];

  List<List<String>> resultList = List();

  List<String> comparatorList = priceList.singleWhere((priceObj) => priceObj.price == 199.0).products;

  productList1.forEach((product) {
    if(comparatorList.contains(product[1])) {
      resultList.add(product);
    }
  });

  productList2.forEach((product) {
    if(comparatorList.contains(product[1])) {
      resultList.add(product);
    }
  });

  print(resultList.toString());
  //Above statement prints [[myName, productid1], [myName, productid3]]

}
```

In the above example first we create the `comparatorList` which contains the names of only those products which are priced at 199.0.

Then, we extract only those items from both the product lists which are present in the `comparatorList` as well. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done to overcome the issue:

```
 Item tempOne,tempTwo;
 for(int i=0; i<prices.listOfProductIds.length;i++){
   for(int j=0; j<itemOne.length; j++){
     if((prices.listOfProductIds[i]) == (itemOne.productId)){
       tempOne = itemOne;
       break; 
     }
   }
  for(int j=0; j<itemTwo.length; j++){
     if((prices.listOfProductIds[i]) == (itemTwo.productId)){
       tempTwo = itemTwo;
       break; 
     }
   }
  Wrapper finalResult = new Wrapper(tempOne,tempTwo,prices[i]);
}
```

Defined wrapper class

```
class Wrapper{
  Item itemOne,itemTwo;
  Price price
  Warpper(this.itemOne,this.itemTwo,this.price)
}
```